# Convert human readable time range to the related amount of seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to figure out how to implement "smart" time parsing as we know it from the `shutdown`command [see manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) in one of my own scripts.

So how could I do these conversions within a bash script?

```
now -> 1448537350
+30 -> 1448539150
+1h -> 1448540950
+1d -> 1448623750
00:00 -> 1448582400
```

My current solution is not very nice and just supports the `+/-XX` format but doesn't really parse the passed in argument and rather just uses the argument for the math:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=$(date "+%s")
let TIME=$TIME$1
echo $TIME
```

Called this way

```
./script.sh +3600 #in 1 hour
```

So is there anything I could reuse to have human readble time ranges as arguments?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
date -d 'now' +%s
date -d '+30min' +%s
date -d '+1hour' +%s
date -d '00:00' +%s
```

I hope that helps. For further reading I suggest [`man date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date).

Comment: argh I tried '+1m' which doesn't work and didn't find the other options in the man page right away - 
btw. `man date` points to `info date`  which is quite extensive ... but that's sth. I oversaw

Comment: @pagid You are welcome. Never knew that `date` has such an extensive `info` page.

Answer (score 1):

If external tool can be used, you can try [dateutil](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/#dateadd) tool.

Here is an example:

> dateadd
>
> A tool to perform date arithmetic (date maths) in the shell. Given a date and a list of durations this will compute new dates. Given a duration and a list of dates this will compute new dates.
>
> `$ dateadd 2010-02-02 +4d`
>
> =>
>
> `2010-02-06`
>
> `$ dateadd 2010-02-02 +1w`
>
> =>
>
> `2010-02-09`
>
> `$ dateadd -1d <<EOF
>   2001-01-05
>   2001-01-01
>   EOF`
>
> =>
>
> `2001-01-04
>      2000-12-31`
>
> Adding durations to times:
>
> `$ dateadd 12:05:00 +10m`
>
> =>
>
> `12:15:00`
>
> and even date-times:
>
> `$ dateadd 2012-03-12T12:05:00 -1d4h`
>
> =>
>
> `2012-03-11T08:05:00`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the argument is human readable with `date` command itself. If not then you can check whether it is numerical or not using **regex**. An example is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=$(date "+%s")

if date -d "$1" "+%s" > /dev/null 2>&1; then ## Human Readable Format
  d=$(date -d "$1" "+%s")
  let TIME=$TIME+$d
  echo $TIME
elif [[ $1 =~ ^[+-]+{1}[0-9]+$ ]]; then ## Numerical Value
  let TIME=$TIME$1
  echo $TIME
else
  echo "Parsing Error!"
fi
```